# bool data sending on razor html page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, boolean, razor-pages

i cant send my bool data to my controller and i dont know why. i allready try out `@using (Html.DropdownList)` and other things.

here is my modal and problem is in `LCategories[i].IsActive` that is the point where i cant send bool data to my controller.

```
                        
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.LCategories.Count(); i++)
{
<div id="categoryUpdate-@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryID" class="modal animated zoomInUp custo-zoomInUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="registerModalLabel">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Kategori Bilgilerini Güncelle</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24"
                         height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"
                         stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                         class="feather feather-x">
                        <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line>
                        <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCategory","Admin", new { id = @Model.LCategories[i].CategoryID }))
            {
               <div class="modal-body">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryID" name="CategoryID" type="hidden" value="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryID">
                    <div class="form-row mb-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryName">Kategori Adı</label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryName" vtype="text" class="form-control"
                              placeholder="Kategori Adı" name="CategoryName" value="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryName" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label  asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryIsFeatured">Öne Çıkarılsın Mı ?</label>
                            <select asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryIsFeatured" class="selectpicker"
                                data-width="100%" name="CategoryIsFeatured" required>
                                <option selected="selected" value="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryIsFeatured">@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryIsFeatured</option>@*Daha sonra düzeltilecek*@
                                <option value="1">Evet</option>
                                <option value="0">Hayır</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row mb-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].IsActive">Durumu</label>
                            <select asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].IsActive" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" name="CategoryIsActive" required>
                                <option selected="selected" value="@Model.LCategories[i].IsActive">@Model.LCategories[i].IsActive</option>
                                <option value='1'>Active</option>
                                <option value='0'>Passive</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row mb-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryLink">Kategori Linki</label>
                            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryLink" class="input-group-text">https://hbksoftware.com.tr/category/</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CategoryLink" asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryLink" 
                                       aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="Link" value="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryLink">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row mb-4" style="text-align: center">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h5>Varolan Kategori Fotoğrafı</h5>
                            <textarea>@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryPhoto"</textarea>
                            @*<img src="" width="250" height="300">*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row mb-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label asp-for="LCategories[i].CategoryPhoto">Kategori Fotoğrafı</label>
                            <input asp-for="LCategories[i].CategoryPhoto" value="@Model.LCategories[i].CategoryPhoto" type="text" class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="Kategori Photo" name="CategoryPhoto" required>
                                                    @*<div class="custom-file-container" data-upload-id="categoryPhotoUpdate">
                                <label>
                                    Seçili Resmi Sil <a href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                        class="custom-file-container__image-clear"
                                                        title="Clear Image">x</a>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-file-container__custom-file">
                                    <input id="categoryPhoto" type="file" name="categoryPhoto"
                                           class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-input"
                                           accept="image/*">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30485760" />
                                    <span class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-control"></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="custom-file-container__image-preview"></div>*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="UpdateCategory" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2 btn-block">Kategoriyi Güncelle</button>
            }
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

i allready check it out my controller and desing pattern,they are working so well.

I edited my question,u can see the whole modal. that modal is activates on the data table.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "can't send"? Where's your form, where's your submit button, what does happen?

Comment: Did you try @true.ToString()? It Produces True : False in razor.

Comment: i dont have a form. i have a table and i have a modal which activates on table. i just cant send that data to my controller on modal

Comment: @adlorem i try it now. its not working too

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,.net core bind model with name attribute,and your propertity name is `IsActive`,but your select name is `CategoryIsActive`.If you want to bind data to IsActive propertity,you need to change name to `IsActive`.
And then you need to change option value to `True,False` as the following shows,`0,1` cannot be binded to bool:

```
<div class="col">
               <label asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].IsActive">Durumu</label>
               <select asp-for="@Model.LCategories[i].IsActive" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" name="CategoryIsActive" required>
                               
                     <option value=True>Active</option>
                     <option value=False>Passive</option>
               </select>
</div>
```